# ejabberd возможно ли сменить метод авторизации

Tags: xmpp

Возможно ли сменить метод авторизации в админку ejabberd?
Это похоже на обычный htaccess который легко брутится, я понимаю что можно сменить адрес админки но, есть ли еще способы повысить безопасность админки?

[image: введите сюда описsadaание изображения]

Comment: Почему вы решили, что "легко брутится"?

Comment: Ну и к htaccess это не имеет абсолютно никакого отношения

Comment: почему я решил что легко брутится? потому что в том же kali есть такие инструменты которым с этими полями работают, нет никакой капчи, тут просто перебирай не хочу.

а про htaccess я это как пример привел.

Comment: Ну и пусть себе работают, это совершенно не значит, что его возможно сбрутить меньше чем за миллиарды лет

Comment: Даже если перебирать со скоростью 100000 паролей в секунду — подобрать 9-символьный пароль без спецсимволов получится лишь за 16 лет, а на 10-символьный пароль потребуется почти 600 лет. Я не думаю, что стоит об этом беспокоиться